# Change position The Custom Related List Button

Tags: related-list

I'm creating custom related list for Files.
I want to put custom button on center position instead of standard file upload  button.
I can put custom button, but the position does not move to center. The button is on the left position. How can I put it to center?

VF Page
FileRelatedList

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:relatedList subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"  list="AttachedContentDocuments" title="Files">
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:outputPanel style="text-align:center;">
                <input type="button" class="btn" style="text-align:right;" value="doSomething" onclick="doSomething;"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:relatedList>
</apex:page>
```

Access vf page
https://login.salesforce.com/apex/FileRelatedList?id=XXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Layout="block"` to render it like a div. In normal case it renderas span and take minimal width. When you render it as div it take complete available with and then put the button in center.

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="button" class="btn" style="text-align:right;" value="doSomething" onclick="doSomething;"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: that's perfect for me, I can put the button on center position finally! thanks a lot!